# How to create shutdown shortcut?

Tags: shortcut, system-shutdown

I want to create shutdown shortcut which is shutdown my pc within 10 second.
what is syntax for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a new shortcut and put this into the location

```
%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -s -f -t 10
```

this will take 10 seconds to shutdown

Answer (score 3):

For windows...

```
shutdown /s /t 10 /f
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's windows, you could write a batch file with `shutdown -t 10` and that should do the trick.